# Check if value of input has changed in a loop for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i want to check if the value of an input has changed or no into a loop for but i have a problem that is **define this function outside of loop for**.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#buttonEnregistrerForcageRevision', function() {
  var element;
  var strRet = '';
  var x = document.getElementById("REVISIONForm").elements.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    element = document.getElementById("REVISIONForm").elements[i];
    $(element).change(function() {
      if (strRet != '') strRet = strRet + ';';
      strRet = strRet + element.id + '=' + element.value;
    });
  }
  $('#RevisionForcage').attr("value", strRet);
  $("#REVISIONForm").submit();
});
```

Here i want to test if the element has changed or no which is the first element in my form of type input text.

Comment: There's several issues here. Firstly selecting an element by its `id` will only ever return one element so the loop is redundant. Secondly, if you want to check if an element's value has changed just apply a `change` event handler to it. That's all that needs to be done. If you could edit the question to include a sample of your HTML we can show you how.

Comment: Agree with previous comment. change event should be attached to `form` components to watch for changes. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, a HTMLFormElement got a propriety `elements` which return the <button>, <fieldset>, <input>, <object>, <output>, <select>, <textarea> of the form. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements

Comment: @samb102 my bad, I entirely forgot about that. I mistakenly assumed the element being selected was a `div` and didn't even notice the `elements` property.